# Wordpress category links are not working on an Nginx server

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, wordpress

I just configured a new server to move my website. After I migrated, everything works fine except for category links. If we visit a category, it will give a 404 error. Page permalinks are working fine! What might be the problem?

The nginx conf :

```
server {
        listen   80;


        root /var/www/androidgadgematic;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name androidgadgematic.com www.androidgadgematic.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 10d;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
       }


        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~ /nginx.conf {
                deny all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location ~ ^/feed/(.+)\.html$ {
                if ($args != '') {
                rewrite ^(.*) $1? permanent;
                }
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }

        include /var/www/androidgadgematic/nginx.conf;
        location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" { add_header "" ""; }
        location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" { }
        location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }
        location /ngx_pagespeed_statistics { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }
        location /ngx_pagespeed_global_statistics { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }
        location /ngx_pagespeed_message { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }
        location /pagespeed_console { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }

        location ^~ /wp-login.php {
                auth_basic            "Restricted Area: WordPress";
                auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/.htpasswd;
                try_files $uri =404;
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }

}
```

PS : Even the wp-admin gives 404

fastcgi.conf:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

PS : I downloaded and compiled Nginx from source to install page speed. Might this be the problem?

Comment: What is in your `fastcgi.conf`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Don't have a `fastcgi.conf` i think. Replaced the line `include fastcgi_params;` with that to fix a site wide 500 or 404 issue.

Comment: You do have a `fastcgi.conf`; if you didn't, then nginx wouldn't load!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Really sorry I found it. Pasted it's content above

Answer (score 0):

move this to bottom:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

And add

```
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

beneath the try_files directive